# Tensorflow Are All Variables Trained?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning

When using tensorflow's automatic differentiation, exactly which variables does it update each iteration?

For instance, if I had a vanilla RNN with a state variable, would automatic differentiation compute it's gradient and update it for each time-step too, since it contributes to the loss?

For instance, the equation for a vanilla RNN would be:

**h_t = X_t W_x + h_{t-1} W_h + b**

How does tensorflow know to update the values of **W_x**, **W_h**, and **b**, but not **h_{t-1}** ?

Sorry if I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: when you call `opt.minimize` you can provide a list of variables you differentiate against, so you can give "h_t", if you wanted to minimize that

Answer (score 0):

State of the RNN is not defined as a trainable tensorflow variable. It's just a node in a graph which is used to connect some other. On the contrary, weights matrices `W_x` and `W_h` are explicitly defined as tensorflow variables with `tf.Variable(..., trainable = True)`. Gradients are computed with respect to the trainable variables, so they are only objects updated during optimization process.